# How do I make voice-to-text work in RPG.SE chat?

Tags: support, chat, accessibility

As I recover from a hand injury, I attempted to use voice-to-text in RPG.SE chat. It did not work. It did work in the upper room. (Christianity.SE chat).

It did work in the title to the question, but it did not work in the body of the question at RPG.SE.  It also does work in the comments under the questions and answers. I am able to voice to text into the meta.se question box.

The feature I am using is windows key + H (Windows 10). This question was posted by doing voice to text into notepad, and then copying and pasting into the question box, and then editing a bit.

Is there a toggle that needs to be switched on at RPG.SE?
I posted a Q at meta.se.

[How do I make voice to text work in SE chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349865/380710)

Comment: it appears to be working now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an odd Windows feature, it appears.  What I discovered, after experimenting on Meta.SE, Christianity.SE, and here is that sometimes, after hitting window + H, to enable voice to text, you have to toggle the little microphone icon on and off once or twice to get it to work in the SE chat or the SE question/answer box. Not sure if Apple stuff behave that way or not.

[image]

I had to do that re-toggle twice simply to post this answer.

Comment: +1 for the freehand drawing in overhead faux-perspective of the triliths surrounding a central stone at Stonehenge , appreciating that this year so many were not able to attend Solstice's sunrise. Most people who haven't been aren't aware of the conjoined pair to the north....

Comment: @nitsua60 I visited Stonehenge in 1971. before the fences went up. Maybe a subliminal thing?